# Read huge dataset with R and UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, bigdata, read.csv

I'm using RStudio and I have a huge data set (30m rows x 5 cols; numbers and text) in .csv format. When I try to import that Dataset, it is "impossible" to read it with `read.csv`, so I installed `library(sqldf)`. With the command `read.csv.sql` I'm able to open my dataset, which takes ~45 minutes. `sqlddf` package can read it, but doesn't have the read.csv option `fileEncoding = 'UTF-8'`, so when I read that file a lot of Unicode characters are wrong, such a Spanish words like "Camión" or "España".

Does anyone knows about the right library or command that allows me to import that huge Dataset with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Try `fread` from `data.table`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.8/topics/fread

Comment: Performance is one thing, handling Unicode files is a different thing entirely. First of all *is* the file UTF8? How did you try to read it? Did you specify the encoding? Please post your code

Comment: As for performance, 30M rows isn't that much.  The problem is that you are trying to *load* all that in the first place into memory. *Don't*. You don't need to load everything into memory to caclulate counts, groups etc, you can read rows one at a time and update counts and totals as you go. By the time you finish reading you'll have all results and you won't even have to allocate more than a few KBs of RAM.

Comment: You could try `fread("filename.csv", encoding = "UTF-8", nrows = 100)`. Just read some rows first for testing... and getting the encoding right.

Comment: SQLite can read CSV files as if they were SQLite tables. This means you can use sqldf and RSQLite to execute queries against the CSV file *without* loading into memory first. You can use this to calculate groupings, and aggregates

Comment: Another, probably better option, is to load those rows into a database. 30M rows isn't a lot for a database like MySQL, Postgres or SQL Server. You can load the data once, add indexes and start querying